# Delphi XE3 - performance issue with TDataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Data processing with XE3 programs take up to 10 times more than with same programs compiled with XE2. This is known issue (probably refers mainly to TStringField), reported to [QC 111942](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111942), but it is not fixed yet. Does anybody have a fix / workaround for this issue?

TIA Branko

Comment: IMHO your only hope is to downgrade or use some third party memory table component

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo - the issue is not TClientDataset specific, I don't even use CDS

Answer (score 0):

Same in XE5. Plus extra traffic and all this client-server thing require >5 Mbit per second (!) to work normally. I am using only TFDConnection and TFDQuery. Specially for MySQL the speed is the same with Delphi components and with third-party driver (libmysql.dll). If you have no FireDAC you can replace TFDQuery with TSQLQuery. Here is a procedure how to fill a string grid:

```
procedure SelGrid(sql:ansiString;Q:TFDQuery;grid:TStringGrid);
var i: integer;
begin
  Q.Close;
  Q.SQL.Text:='';
  Q.Open(sql);
  grid.ColCount:=Q.FieldCount;
  grid.RowCount:=1;
  while not Q.Eof do begin
    for i := 0 to grid.ColCount-1 do grid.Cells[i,grid.RowCount-1]:=Q.Fields.Fields[i].AsString;
    grid.RowCount:=grid.RowCount+1;
    Q.Next;
  end;
  Q.Close;
  if grid.RowCount>1 then grid.RowCount:=grid.RowCount-1;
  grid.Row:=0;
  //AutoSizeGridColumns(grid,30,200);
end;
```

This is VCL string grid. Of course you muse deal with updates and so on, but you'll have no more performance problems.

Comment: QC item 111942 is marked as resolved in XE4. Are you sure it is the same issue? (The WC entry includes a test application to measure the performance for this specific problem)

Comment: No, I am not sure, but with MySQL5 I had performance issues, which dissapeared with 3rd party connection. After that I start trying and found that with TFDConnection and TFDQuery performance is the same like libmysql.dll, so I rebuilt the app with TFDConnection and TFDQuery. Now I'm not dealing with databases, so this was just an old memory.